# Can't set Default Values For Number and String Types in Ember Models

Tags: types, model, ember.js, default, ember-data

I'm trying to set default types in an Ember Model, but only some types work:

```
  createdDate: DS.attr('date', {defaultValue: new Date()}) // Works
  createdDate: DS.attr('boolean', {defaultValue: false}) // Works
  createdDate: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: "example"}) // Doesn't work - attribute null
  createdDate: DS.attr('number', {defaultValue: 99}) // Doesn't work - attribute null
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

According to [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_attr), all your code is fine.
However, [looks like](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/b4a415e1be4db3673a102b3fdc45b6bd22d46d59/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/attributes.js#L63-65) the defaultValue only handles the `undefined` cases (your boolean and date).
You may try to handle those `null` cases with a function you'll pass a second argument.